# VScode integrated termial fails to launch

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here's the situation. I was testing a basic proxy application. But I made a mistake, and the proxy fell into a infinite print loop. So I terminated the terminal that was going on a loop, and suddenly, vscode won't let me use integrated terminal. The error reads,

```
"The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (forkpty(3) failed.)."
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using another terminal to log in to the shell and forcefully quit all of the processes. This was not a problem of vscode but a problem of having abnormal processes running on the remote server.